# KQL list of strings contains any value of list of strings

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have an API that executes some KQL.

I'm executing a KQL that filters all rows such that some column (that is of type list of string) contains any of the values in some given list of strings.

Basically:

```
let foo1 = datatable(d: dynamic) [
    dynamic([""]),
    dynamic(["foobar"]),
    dynamic(["Alice", "Bob"]),
    dynamic(["Alice"])
];
foo1
| where d has_any (dynamic(["Alice", "otherthing"]))
```

Which outputs the last 2 rows as I expect - I wanted all rows where `d` has any of the values `"Alice", "otherthing"`.

Everything works as expected, until I want all rows that contain the empty string value:

```
let foo1 = datatable(d: dynamic) [
    dynamic([""]),
    dynamic(["foobar"]),
    dynamic(["Alice", "Bob"]),
    dynamic(["Alice"])
];
foo1
| where d has_any (dynamic([""]))
```

and the result above outputs all rows, instead of only the first row, which has the empty string value.

1. Why?
2. What can I change in order for it to work as I expect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### 1.

Apparently any string has the empty string, e.g.:

```
print "abc" has ""
```

| print_0 |
| --- |
| true |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAysoyswrUVBKTEpWUshILFZQUgIATQiTxxIAAAA=)

##### 2.

It seems you are looking for a full match and not a partial match.
In this case, `has` might lead to undesired results, e.g.:

```
print dynamic(["The story of Alice in wonderland", "Bob"]) has "Alice"
```

| print_0 |
| --- |
| true |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAysoyswrUUipzEvMzUzWiFYKyUhVKC7JL6pUyE9TcMzJTE5VyMxTKM/PS0ktyknMS1HSUVByyk9SitVUyEgsVlACK1ECAHaq/glGAAAA)

#### Solution:

[set_intersect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/setintersectfunction)

```
let foo1 = datatable(d: dynamic) [
    dynamic([""]),
    dynamic(["foobar"]),
    dynamic(["Alice", "Bob"]),
    dynamic(["Alice"])
];
foo1
| where array_length(set_intersect(dynamic(["Alice", "otherthing"]), d)) > 0
```

| d |
| --- |
| ["Alice","Bob"] |
| ["Alice"] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3WOwQrCMBBE74H8w5BTAj3oVVHQ3yilpMnaBGIC6YIU/HhT8CR19zTz2JlNxHiUcsQF3nLbKZH2J/g122d0Br0UaPPVuldqMN2v1xImW/fILUVHqoO6l%20k/H4wUw1mK7RMp3ngFqgRbq13HRHnmoBfiMWamupBjvVNQuB1xiHneeuCNwRWHD8w6uEPgAAAA)

```
let foo1 = datatable(d: dynamic) [
    dynamic([""]),
    dynamic(["foobar"]),
    dynamic(["Alice", "Bob"]),
    dynamic(["Alice"])
];
foo1
| where array_length(set_intersect(dynamic([""]), d)) > 0
```

| d |
| --- |
| [""] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3WOTQoCMRSD94XeIXTVwix0qyjoNYYy9OfpFGoLnQcy4OGt4EbRZJV8EJKJcal1iwOi426fSccd4lrcLQWDUQp0vbMelbJm%20O76gnftFznlFEgNUOfq/3NrpLB7KV5PpHjgPlMjuNbcOmUqV571QjylwtQWCqw/7yAagyM2Twr6vkfNAAAA)